# Find a part of string in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I got a array like this

```
$a = ['foo', 'bar', 'toto', 'tata'];
```

And i have a long string like

```
$s = 'bla b   blabababa  fooblbl';
```

I would like to fond if there is some occurrence of $a in my string $s.

I tried to do this with `in_array` and `strpos` but i can't get through.

Any tips?

Comment: How did you use those?

Comment: A great tip would be first to attempt to solve this yourself before posting here. Please show us some of your attempts (even if they don't really work).

Comment: Did you try `array_map()` ?

Comment: @MaxiCapodacqua array_map is not meanth to be used as foreach. `if (in_array('yes!',array_map(create_function("$key,$val",'if (strpos("'.$s.'",$val) !== false) return "yes!";')))) echo 'yay!';`. you can replace 'yes!' with 'true' but it still looks rediculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($a as $b) 
    if (strpos($s,$b) !== false)
        echo 'yay!';
```

Comment: @IanBrindley I updated the code to find the number of array entries that are found in the string. good stuff! `function arrayStrPos($array,$str) { ob_start(); foreach($array as $b) if (strpos($str,$b)) echo 'yay!'; $out = ob_get_clean ();  return $out ? strlen($out) / strlen('yay!') : 0; }`. This is how i write all my code man!

Comment: @DoXicK Haha I would love to see some production code like that! Counts using a string literals length! I bet you walk into jobs :)

Comment: @IanBrindley i have seen worse! `for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) if ($i < 5) continue; .... }`. We all know web development isn't about performance.  It's about making it work! (No, i actually do take pride in my code, so this stuff doesn't show up in my production code, haha).

Answer (score 0):

A simple method

```
foreach($array as $item){
  if(strpos($item,"mysearchword")!== false){


// handle the response



}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = ['foo', 'bar', 'toto', 'tata'];

$s = 'bla b   blabababa  fooblbl';

$result = array_filter(
    $a,
    function($value) use ($s) {
        return (strpos($s, $value) !== false);
    }
);
var_dump($result);
```

returns $result containing all elements from $a that were found in $s